# Django: Insert Record in 1 table, updated another table

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to insert a record into one table and update another, but I'm stumbling on the correct approach.

When I run the code below, it successfully inserts a new record into the Checkin table and sets the adult PK value.  It also successfully updates the WaiverAdult table by setting the status to True, as expected.

But, I'd also like to save the "checkintime" to Checkin, but I'm sure how.  Any direction and details (to better learn) are greatly appreciated.

I have two models:

**Models (a simplified representation) :**

```
class WaiverAdult(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)


class CheckIn(models.Model):
    adult = models.ForeignKey(
        WaiverAdult, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='adult_checkin')

    checkintime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    checkoutime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is my view:

```
def checkin(request):
    
    waiver_id = request.POST.get('id')

    action = request.POST.get('action')

    if waiver_id and action:
        try:
            
            adult = WaiverAdult.objects.get(id=waiver_id)

            if action == 'checkmein':

                c = CheckIn(adult=adult)
                c.save()

                adult.status = True
                adult.save()

...
```

Thank you.

Comment: If this code isn't working, please explain.

Comment: I updated the post with some more details.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried something like `c.checkintime = datetime.datetime.now()` ?

Comment: I don't understand the difficulty.  `c = CheckIn(adult=adult, checkintime=xyz)`, where `xyz` is whatever datetime value you want.

Comment: Thank you.  c.checkintime = datetime.datetime.now() worked for me.  My issue was that I originally tried c.checkintime = datetime.now()

Comment: So your question wasn't really about django records at all, it was "how do i get the current time"?

Comment: django’s DateTimeField provides auto_now_add=True option, which will set checkintime to now when the object is first created.